# Is it in Python possible to set the last parameter of several in a function call?

Tags: python, ftp, timeout

Is it in Python possible to set the last parameter of several in a function call if all have a default value?

Example: in the `ftplib.FTP` the module defines this:

```
ftplib.FTP([host[, user[, passwd[, acct[, timeout]]]]])
```

All these parameters have a default value, so you don´t need to set them all, you could, for example, just call `ftp = ftplib.FTP()` to get a FTP object. But what if I would like to set only the `timeout` parameter? How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by using named arguments you can specify the value with a name-value pair.

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP(timeout=100)
```

Comment: Thank you, you answered first so you get the correct answer marking. But both get votes by me :)

Answer (score 5):

You can pass this (or any other) parameter by name:

```
ftplib.FTP(timeout=10)
```